# How to add padding-left to text that is already floated right?

Tags: html, css

Link: http://neilson.webege.com/principals.html

I want to add 10px of padding in between the picture and the text.

The text is currently floated right. When I tried to put padding-left in one of the P classes, nothing changed.

Any tips?

```
<div class="eachprincipal">
<img src="images/principalpic.jpg" style="float:left;padding-right: 10px;">
<br>
<br>
<p style="float:right">
</p><p class="principalname"> Jack Zakariaie, J.D. </p>
<br>
<p class="principaldescription"> Jack of the house Zakariaie, the First of his Name, King of the Andals and the Rhoynar and the First Men, Lord of the Seven Kingdoms and Protector of the Realm has fed all the starving children in the world by causing photosynthesis in farm plants by reflecting light off his bald head.</p><p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the html and css for this

Comment: Linking to a webpage is not preferred on this site. Please include the relevant CSS and HTML in your question.

Comment: Wrap the image in it's own div and pad it. The HTML alone needs to be cleaned up quite a bit.

Comment: There's not really much use in these empty paragraphs floated to right. And probably you should consider using paddings and margins instead of stacking line break elements (`<br>`).

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it currently, the padding should be added to the image, not the paragraph.

```
.eachprincipal > img {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```